# Read the contents of a folder randomly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have this piece of code that allows me to read the contents of the gallery of the phone and scroll randomly its contents.

```
public static Uri getRandomImage(ContentResolver resolver) {

    String[] projection = new String[] {
        BaseColumns._ID

    };

    Random rand = new Random();
    int p = 2 + rand.nextInt(8-2+1); 

    Uri uri = p == 0 ? Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI : Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor =  Media.query(resolver, uri, projection, null, MediaColumns._ID);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            return null;
    }

    cursor.moveToPosition(new Random().nextInt(cursor.getCount()));

    return Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, cursor.getString(0));
}
```

But I would like to modify this code to read the contents of a folder set by me. How can I do this?

thank you very much

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ ?

Comment: I already put in a folder created by me a set of files, as soon as the application is installed and started. I tried to change the code I posted, using this: Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/MyFolder/");

Comment: I gave you starting point: http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/10/list-filesdirectory-in-android.html to read files in directory. From this, you can just easily get random files in it by putting the files first to array.

Comment: basically my problem is very simple, the URI should not be Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , but a path specified from me; and the cursor should spostari random in that folder.

Comment: you cannot open a cursor on a directory. Media is a content provider that abstracts the file structure. Use File

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the easiest way to do: name each file in your folder numerically i.e. (supposing they are all jpg) name them 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on. Now all you need to do is generate an array of distinct random numbers between 1 and number of files in your folder and generate a uri by concatenating this random numbers with `.jpg` and then display them.

Comment: basically my problem is very simple, the URI should not be Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , but a path specified from me; and the cursor should spostari random in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set the URI to a different value?

```
Random rand = new Random();
int p = 2 + rand.nextInt(8-2+1); 

Uri uri = p == 0 ? Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI : Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

This code always sets the URI to Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ... no matter what the value of the integer p is...
Personally I actually can't even see what you are trying to do there...

Comment: basically my problem is very simple, the URI should not be Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , but a path specified from me; and the cursor should spostari random in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Getting random files out or selected directory is quite easy.

You can use this snippet:

```
private File getRandomFile(File root) {
    File[] files = root.listFiles();

    Random randomizer = new Random();       
    return files[randomizer.nextInt(files.length - 1)];
}
```

If you need the method to return `Uri`, you can change the return and method signature:

```
private Uri getRandomFile(File root) {
    File[] files = root.listFiles();

    Random randomizer = new Random();       
    File f = files[randomizer.nextInt(files.length - 1)];
    return Uri.fromFile(f); 
}
```

As for `cursor` requirement, you should be able to wrap this method to another method and bridge request accordingly.

Comment: thank you, but in my application I need to Uri and Cursor, because my methods return Uri and Cursor